# Problem with loading (jqery / css) CiviCRM files in Joomla 3.4.8

Tags: joomla

Jqery / css etc. CiviCRM files from the folder: components/com_civicrm are not loaded.

In another site they are loaded well, see links below.

Both sites are in Joomla 3.4.8 with CiviCRM 4.7.3.
Both sites use the latest version of admin tools to protect the site.

Thank you for your help!

http://www.cecsweden.org/cms/registration-festival-sweden-2016
http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/gP8gq/http://www.cecsweden.org/cms/registration-festival-sweden-2016

https://www.srivast.org/en/register
http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/eaOYc7/https://www.srivast.org/en/register

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that your paths are set correctly. In the menu go to Administer > System Settings > Resource URLs and correct the CiviCRM Resource URL. (if the menu isn't working, type directly the path `civicrm/admin/setting/url&reset=1` to get there) In 4.7 in most cases it should simply be `[civicrm.root]/`.

If you're unclear what the correct url should be, try doing "view source" in your browser and check what urls are being prepended to Civi's js/css files - what about it is incorrect? That should give a hint of what needs fixing.

Comment: thank you for your help. the site is now displayed fine. the name administrator was missing in the url name. i dont know why it was missing. in the other civicrm instance it was not missing.